# Не работает ini_set()

Tags: php

```
       ini_set('session.auto_start', 1);
$r =    ini_get('session.auto_start');

var_dump($r);

// string(1) "0"
```

В чем вообще дело? И так не только с session.auto_start, но и с другими session.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас достаточно свежая версия PHP, то session.auto_start нельзя установить в скрипте. PHP_INI_PERDIR - Значение может быть установлено в php.ini, .htaccess или httpd.conf .